# Are Hamas leaders billionaires?

Tags: finance, hamas

Various right-wing sources ranging from the [New York Post](https://nypost.com/2023/11/07/news/hamas-leaders-worth-11bn-live-luxury-lives-in-qatar/) to [Fox News](https://www.foxnews.com/world/hamas-billionaires-lifestyles-of-rich-terrorists) have reported that the top Hamas leaders are all billionaires.

> Hamas leaders worth staggering $11B revel in luxury — while Gaza’s people suffer

or

> Hamas bosses Khaled Mashaal and Ismail Haniyeh are worth an estimated $4 billion each, and political bureau leader Mousa Abu Marzouk is worth $3 billion.

Although left-wing [US] sources probably are not in love with Hamas either, I don't see them repeating those claims as readily, at least not in headlines.

So, what's the actual evidence that Hamas leaders are all billionaires?

Comment: I'm less familiar with Canadian newspapers, but the 11 billion claim has been repeated in a subheading in https://nationalpost.com/news/world/israel-middle-east/hamas-money as it's been pointed out to me. A quick check on Wikipedia suggests that's a right-wing website though, for the Canadian def thereof.

Comment: According to [Media of Canada - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_of_Canada#Newspapers), the National Post is one of only two nationally distributed newspapers, and is published by Postmedia/Sun Media, which is by far the country's largest newspaper publisher.  My biased impression is that Canada's typical main-stream right-wing is perhaps slightly left of the American Democrat party.